# Need help manipulating an image in android - convert to greyscale

Tags: android, image, bitmap, uri

I am an Android newbie and I need your help. I am trying to create simple apps, and in one of them, I want to convert a color image to greyscale, just by using algorithmic methods. I made it possible to select an image using Uri and ImageView to show it on screen, but I need to make it possible to manipulate the image. I think that Bitmap class is the way to go, but I need some guidance for using the correct methods.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get a Bitpmap from an Uri:

```
Uri imageUri;//you say you already have this
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
//now call the method below to get the grayscale bitmap
Bitmap greyBmp = toGrayscale( bitmap );
//set the ImageView to the new greyscale
Imageview my_img_view = (Imageview ) findViewById (R.id.my_img_view);//your imageview
my_img_view.setImageBitmap( greyBmp );
```

Here is a  method to convert a color Bitmap to greyscale Bitmap:

```
    public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
        {        
            int width, height;
            height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
            width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

            Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, 
Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(0);
            ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
            paint.setColorFilter(f);
            c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
            return bmpGrayscale;
        }
```